# public const doesn't override private const function?

Tags: c++, constants, overriding

I have a class with a header like this:

```
public:
    const dtMeshTile* getTile(int i) const;

private:
    dtMeshTile* getTile(int i);
```

When I try to use it like this:

```
const dtMeshTile* const tile = navmesh->getTile(i);
```

I'm getting a "'dtMeshTile* getTile(int)' is private within this context" How can I specify the public function?

Comment: could      .... const* navtmpmesh= navmesh;       navmesg->getTile(i);  work?

Comment: `const_cast<const ClassType*>(navmesh)->getTile();`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, which function the compiler chooses to call never is decided by return type (which is why you can't have int foo(int) and void foo(int)). Have you tried casting navmesh to a pointer to a const object?

Also, the fact that you need a cast to deal with choosing the "correct" function probably means you need to re-work your API.

Comment: navmesh has to be const to make that call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
#include <cstdlib>

class Bar {}; 
class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo (Bar& bar)
    :   
        mBar (bar)
    {   
    }   
    const Bar& get() const
    {   
        return mBar;
    }   
private:
    Bar& get()
    {   
        return mBar;
    }   

    Bar& mBar;
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo foo (bar);
    Bar& ref = foo.get();
}
```

At the point of the call: `const Bar& ref = foo.get();` you might expect the `const` version of `get()` to be called, because you are assigning a `const` reference.

But this is not the case.  Return types are not a part of a function's (or method's) signature, so when the compiler is looking for which function to call in a list of possible overloads, the return type is not considered. (In fact, the Standard rejects function overloads which differ only by return type.)

So, how *does* the compiler decide which function to call?  By looking at the information is does have available to it.  The tweo overloads are identical in terms of parameters (both are `void`), so the only thing it has to go on is the static type of the object used to make the call: `foo`.  That static type in this case is `Foo` -- decidedly non-`const`.

Therefore it tried to call the only function it can: the non-`const` version of `get()`. Which of course won't compile because that is `private`.

In order to fox this, the static type can be changed to be a `const Foo` (or something similar), like this:

```
Foo foo (bar);
Bar& ref = foo.get();
```

Or maybe...

```
Foo foo (bar);
const Bar& ref = static_cast <const Foo&> (foo).get();
```

But in practice, I would rather advise that the names of these functions be unambigious, rather that relying on such "tricks" to contort the compiler in to doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation. You touched on most everything I was confused about.

Answer (score 1):

make sure navmesh is const in the context of your call. But I would not recommend const_cast it, you might read this http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/overview-const.html .

Comment: Why are you against `const_cast` in this case? It's perhaps not the best solution to the entire problem, but it's a reasonable way to call the correct function.

Answer (score 1):

You're hit by a pretty common design flow -- an overload set with mixed semantics. 
But I guess you can't change the class, only work around it.

Your problem comes from overload resolution rules. The function is selected based on arguments. Only. private/public stuff is ignored at this stage. The selection happens based on the type before -> if if it's const T*, the first function is selected, for T* the second.

Assess check is applied then, so for the latter case you get the error report. To force the desired function you must use a cast, or better create a free wrapper function

```
const dtMeshTile* getXXXTile(const XXX* p, int i) {return p->getTitle(i);}
```

(or a ref-taking variant).

In my codebase the second function would have a different name, as obtaining a mutable string is way different in semantics.